# How to specify optional dependencies for a makefile

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile

I am recent convert to GNU make use. And I am trying to abuse Makefile for all kind of file manipulations because of the parallelism and checkpoint facilities that Makefile provides. Here is my problem:

I have lot of pdf files that I parse to csv. The pdf files are in hierarchical folder structure:

```
level1/
   level2_1/
      level3_1_1.pdf
      level3_1_2.pdf
   level2_2/
      level3_2_1.pdf
      level3_2_2.pdf
```

I have my script with the rule:

```
%.csv: %.pdf
      python parsepdf.py $< $@
```

But now I want to concatenate all these files. The easy way is using a simple find script

```
cat $(find level1/ -name '*.csv') > level1/level1.csv
```

However, I want to do it in a way that follows a dependency hierarchy with a intermediate csv created at each level of the hierarchy. I assume this approach will exploit the advantage of parallelism with make -j.

```
level1/level2_1/level_2_1.csv : level1/level2_1/level3_1_1.csv level1/level2_1/level3_1_2.csv
         cat $* > $@
level1/level2_2/level_2_2.csv : level1/level2_2/level3_2_1.csv level1/level2_2/level3_2_2.csv
         cat $* > $@
level1/level1.csv : $(wildcard level1/level2_*.csv)
         cat $* > $@
```

But the above method as two problems:

- Even if one of the csv file is not there, the level up csv file won't be created. My requirement is such that even if one file is there, I should go ahead and create a level up csv file.
- How to automatically generate these rules for both levels (ok to assume only two levels) in the hierarchy. Each level can have different number of pdf files.

Is Makefile a good tool for such tasks? If yes, what is the most Makefile'ish  way to specify this target in makefile?

Comment: Make is a very good tool for processing some files to write other files.  However, your question and examples are not clear.  You need to read your question and ask yourself 'can someone who does not know it already, understand what I am writing'.  If you have trouble putting yourself in this position,  have someone else read this, without you telling them anything, and you will see whether they understand.  I bet they won't.  

Once you have your question written well, I will answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess what it is that you want, since it is not really clear from your question.

Using `find`, wildcards or `$(wildcard)` to generate lists of prerequsites is a bad practice.  Avoid it.  Just list them explicitly.  If you need to automate this process, you can always have some script initially generate the Makefile for you, and edit it by hand later as necessary.

Then you can have

```
define CONCATENATE_RULE                                                         
$1: $2 Makefile                                                                 
        cat $2 > $1                                                             
endef                                                                           

$(eval $(call CONCATENATE_RULE, level1/level2_1/level_2_1.csv,\
    level1/level2_1/level3_1_1.csv \
    level1/level2_1/level3_1_2.csv \
))


$(eval $(call CONCATENATE_RULE, level1/level2_2/level_2_2.csv,\
    level1/level2_2/level3_2_1.csv \
    level1/level2_2/level3_2_2.csv \
))
```